# How to read Spring Boot application.properties in ReactJs app?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

We have 2 configuration files: one is in our Spring Boot application (application.properties) and another in our ReactJs app (we use .env in create-react-app). It was decided to use Spring Boot application.properties also in ReactJs app. Can anyone please guide me how can I achieve this?
I have read about "properties-reader" and tried to use it, but I don't have webpack.config.js file in our ReactJs app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thymeleaf** provides the easiest way to pass data from application.properties file to Javascript via the template (index.html) file.

Alternatively, it can be done using normal **JSP** also.

**Here are the working examples:**

---

## Option 1:  Thymeleaf

**Step 1:**   Define the interesting data attributes as hidden elements in the index.html file

```
<div id="root"></div>  ---> Div to be updated by react
....
<span id="myData" hidden></span>

<!-- Script to set variables through  Thymeleaf -->
              
<script th:inline="javascript"> 
    var myData = "[${myData}]]";
    document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML = myData;
</script>
```

**Important note:**
Make sure that the same **index.html** file exists in the '**/public**' folder of Reactjs project as well as in the **/src/main/resources/templates/** folder of the spring boot project.

**Step 2:** Use **model.addAttribute()** method in Spring Boot to invoke Thymeleaf for setting data in the index.html file

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {

    // Get the value of my.data from application.properties file
    @Value("${my.data}")
    private String myData;

    // Call Thymeleaf to set the data value in the .html file
    model.addAttribute("myData", myData);

    return "index";
}
```

**Step 3:**   Update the ReactJS code to read the interesting attribute using document.getElementById

`let myData = document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML`

**More information:**

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining

https://attacomsian.com/blog/thymeleaf-set-javascript-variable

---

## Option 2:  JSP

**Step 1:**   Define the interesting data attributes as hidden elements in the index.jsp file

**Location of index.jsp:**  src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Head section here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Div to be updated by react -->
        <div id="root">
        </div>

        <!-- Include the interesting attribute as a hidden field -->
        <span id="myData" hidden>${myData}</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Important note:**

Make sure that the **/public/index.html** file of reactjs project has the same content (`<body>...</body>`) as that of the **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp** file of spring boot project)

**Step 2:** Use **map.put()** in Spring Boot controller to update data in JSP

```java
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomePageController{

    // Read data from application.properties
    @Value("${my.data}")
    private String myData;

    // Update data attributes of JSP using map.put
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index( Map<String, Object> map ) {
        map.put("myData", myData);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**   Update the ReactJS code to read the interesting attribute using document.getElementById

`let myData = document.getElementById("myData").innerHTML`

**More information:**

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use Thymeleaf in the project. Is it possible to do the same, for example, with .jsp page?

Comment: I updated the answer with the option for using JSP.

Comment: Thank you so much!